# How to transform a data.frame Long to Wide, but not using factors and not equal length associations

Tags: r, out-of-memory

I've tried a few solutions but they don't fit into this use case. I've got 32 GB of RAM and I'm still hitting the ceiling when cast, dcast, or spread are used. I looped to find a list and it took more than 24 hours to do a portion of the 42 million rows I have. I'd like a base solution using the apply family, but I understand if that's not gonna work... I feel like it won't since I have to query the following row to determine if the addressID matches (or if the data.frame is unsorted, it has to search the rest of the column).

Here's an example of a (sorted) data.frame:

```
addressID   MAKE 
104554      LINCOLN                             
104554      LINCOLN                             
104628      HYUNDAI                             
104628      TOYOTA                              
104628      SUBARU                              
104677      HYUNDAI                             
104677      HYUNDAI
```

I want the long format, or a list, such that I've got:

```
$`104554`
[1] LINCOLN LINCOLN

$`104628`
[1] HYUNDAI TOYOTA SUBARU

$`104677`
[1] HYUNDAI HYUNDAI
```

I'm gonna have some addresses with 6 cars. I've got at least 45 MAKEs of cars, so I'd prefer not to have a 20 million X 50 column matrix/data.frame the way that dcast, cast, spread, etc. seem to require to make this run (they're not working due to the RAM limits). I feel like this should be an easy solution, but it escapes me.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `split`. It will create the list that you have in your second code block. Something like `myList <- split(df, df$addressID)`. It should be more efficient than any reshape function.

Comment: This works great. It gives my exact desired output when running `myList <- split(df[,"MAKE"], df$addressID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will
`aggregate(addressID ~ MAKE, data = df, c)`
work for you?

Alternatively,
`by(df, df[,"addressID"], c)`
will give you a list

Comment: If you flip the formula in aggregate() it works. Super easy... Wish I thought of it. Also didn't realize how easy it is to populate a data.frame with a column of lists...

Comment: The by() command would give a better output as `by(df[,"MAKE"],df[,"addressID"],c)`

Comment: I edited to make the changes I mentioned in the previous comments.

Comment: Returning to keep this post honest. `split` and `aggregate` never finished. The routines quickly became bogged down when going from 10000 rows to 100000 rows. I waited about 2 minutes and gave up. `by` is the winner operating on the same 100000 rows in 7.5 seconds.